# err_connection_refused android studio

Tags: android, laravel

I have completed my larval project, I need to create a mobile app. I decide to make a webview to display my laravel into it.
mainactivity

```
package com.example.app;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // REMOTE RESOURCE
         mWebView.loadUrl("https://127.0.0.1:8000");
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // LOCAL RESOURCE
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

mywebviewclient

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getHost() != null && uri.getHost().contains("https://127.0.0.1:8000")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

i have created a network_security_config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://127.0.0.1:8000</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and i added the internet permission in manifest. 
i got this problem
[image: err_connection_refused (view image)]

Comment: try replacing 127.0.0.1 by your system IP address where your server is running
something like 192.168.

Comment: I add the port or not 192.168.x..x:8000 ?

Comment: you have to add port https://192.168.x.x:8000/

Comment: Same problem ..

Comment: Any idea guys ??